# Ember.js: Query param manipulated?

Tags: javascript, rest, url, ember.js, base64

I'm using the query parameter feature of ember to verify an account on my server with an activation-url.

The urls looks like this:

`http://myapp/activation/?id=ZDE2ZTE2MTItYTFmMC00Zjk1LWJhZGUtMGYwNWE1ZDA2ZmRl&code=OGQ4MTQyYzQ5MTVjMGIxNGY4ZDk4MDYxMWRiZGU4N2EzMjY3ZDRhZA==`

The parameters from the server are Base64-encoded.

My activation.js controller somewhere does this:

```
    Em.$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/activation",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.get("id"),
            code: this.get("code")
        }),
        success: function () {
           // ...
        },
        error: function () {
            // ...
        }
```

The server receives receives the correct id but the code is slightly different at the end. The trailing `==` characters of the code parameter are cut off.

I could fix this by just appending them manually:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    id: this.get("id"),
    code: this.get("code") + "=="
}),
```

This doesn't look very reliable.

Interestingly, if I decode the string: `console.log(atob(this.get("code")));` the result is correct, the trailing characters are included.

I'm confused. Can someone tell me if there's a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

UPDATE:

It looks stupid but it seems to be a reliable workaround:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    id: this.get("id"),
    code: btoa(atob(this.get("code")))
}),
```

Comment: Hello Doe, i am facing a similar problem, did you get a solution for this.

Comment: @whyAto8 As you [already found out yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436383/ember-query-params-ignoring-character/41438460#41438460), ember behaves correctly - the equal sign needs to be encoded. What I call a "reliable workaround" above, actually works as reliable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doe. I also agree with your solution above.

Answer (score 2):

The "=" character serves as padding for the base64 encoding (the length of the encoded string "must" be a multiple of 4). However, if the decoding algorithm you use handles paddingless strings, you don't have to do anything about your string. In your case,

```
OGQ4MTQyYzQ5MTVjMGIxNGY4ZDk4MDYxMWRiZGU4N2EzMjY3ZDRhZA==
```

is the same as

```
OGQ4MTQyYzQ5MTVjMGIxNGY4ZDk4MDYxMWRiZGU4N2EzMjY3ZDRhZA
```

You can check that here http://www.base64decode.org/